# Dialogflow sys.location to detect full address (?)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I cant find a why to handle this situation:

**Agent:** Tell me your address

**User** Via j.f. Kennedy, Padova

in my weebhook I would like to receive something like:

```
{city:"Padova", streets:"Via John Fitzgerald Kennedy"}
```

instead of the value of the street detect by dialogflow using sys.location:

```
{city:"Padova", streets:"Via j.f Kennedy"}
```

My goal is to have the **full** name of the streets in my weebhook, I read https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/system-entities but I dont find help to my problem. If its not possible handle this with diaolog flow theres another way?

Comment: i dont think its possible with dialogflow, but after getting location in the webhook you can use some third party address/location api

Answer (score 0):

as said by [sid8491](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196845/sid8491), in dialogflow it isn't possible, you need to use a weebhook to pass the address that you are getting from the user to an API, I had the same issue and here in France, the government has an API which list all the addresses in France. If the address isn't known, the API return a list of the most matching addresses.

Often postal compagnies have this kind of API

Comment: Can confirm. I was working with Indian addresses, so I put some fake samples in my training set, it never generalized beyond the training set. Hell, it didn't even detect the one I had in the training sample.

Comment: I can't confirm it this works but it might be worth checking out: https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal