# Dialogflow - Location action incorrect

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, nlp, location, dialogflow-es

I am having a strange issue with Dialogflow where it is not detecting the full location from a string. It works perfectly fine with UK addresses but when trying US/CA addresses it falls down.

For example I send: **6504 129th ave**

and get the following returned:

```
    "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "zip-code": "",
        "street-address": "129 th ave",
        "subadmin-area": "",
        "country": "",
        "city": "",
        "shortcut": "",
        "business-name": "",
        "admin-area": "",
        "island": ""
      },
      "location.original": "129th ave"
    }
```

I have tried training the intent by highlighting the entire string and selecting @sys.location however I get the following warning in the validation tab:

> The annotated text '6504 129th ave' in training phrase '6504 129th ave' does not correspond to entity type '@sys.location'. Consider annotating text '129th ave' instead.

The error:
[image]

Comment: Do all the US/CA addresses fail? Have you tried to input other known/existing addresses? Or addresses that are just made up?

Comment: Hi @RallyH Yes I have tried a long list of addresses. When they are in this format it just wont detect the first few numbers (building number). The addresses are all real.

Comment: Can you share the code you used for this fulfillment? Have you tried to use @sys.address instead?

Comment: Hi @RallyH Yes, I get the same issue with sys.address. We are using the maps prebuilt agent and havent changed any of the code in there apart from add a few addresses that have returned the error mentioned. I will edit the original post to add the intent.

Comment: I found this SO thread that mentions after getting location in the webhook you can use some third party address/location api. There is a possibility that the maps prebuilt agent you are using in the fulfillment does not contain the addresses that are failing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021254